# Tic Tac Toe in python. How to make it so you can't overwrite other players positions?

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

Let's say player X puts a point at a1 on the board. How do I make it so that player O can't just put their point on a1 and overwrite X's input?

```
board = ["# ", "# ", "# ", "# ", "# ", "# ", "# ", "# ", "# "]
p2 = 1
p = 0
scorex = 0
scoreo = 0
a = 0
b = 0 
def game():
    for i in range(0,3):
        print(board[i], end="")
    print("")
    for i in range(3,6):
        print(board[i], end="")
    print("")
    for i in range(6,9):
        print(board[i], end="")
def pagain(scoreo, scorex):
       again = input("Do you want to play again(y)or no(n)?: ")
       if again == "y":  
              board.clear()
              for i in range(9):
                     board.append("# ")
              p = 0
              wholegame(scoreo, scorex)
              return scoreo


       elif again == "n":
              p = 1
              print("Thanks for playing!")
              o = input("")

def wholegame(scoreo, scorex):
       game()
       p = 0
       while p == 0:

#For O
           o = input("\nWhere do you want to place your O letter?(a1, a2, a3...): ")

           if o == "a1":
               board[0] = "o "
               game()
               
           elif o == "a2":
               board[1] = "o "
               game()
           elif o == "a3":
               board[2] = "o "
               game()
           elif o == "b1":
               board[3] = "o "
               game()
           elif o == "b2":
               board[4] = "o "
               game()
           elif o == "b3":
               board[5] = "o "
               game()
           elif o == "c1":
               board[6] = "o "
               game()
           elif o == "c2":
               board[7] = "o "
               game()
           elif o == "c3":
               board[8] = "o "
           else:
               print("\nInvalid, you lost your turn.")
               
               
               
             
#O Wins
           if board[0] + board[1] + board[2] == "o o o ":
               scoreo = scoreo + 1
               print("\n\nO Wins\nPlayer O has", scoreo, "point(s)")
               p = p + 1
               pagain(scoreo, scorex)
               
           elif board[3] + board[4] + board[5] == "o o o ":
               scoreo = scoreo + 1
               print("\n\nO Wins\nPlayer O has", scoreo, "point(s)")
               p = p + 1
               pagain(scoreo, scorex)
               
           elif board[6] + board[7] + board[8] == "o o o ":
               scoreo = scoreo + 1
               print("\n\nO Wins\nPlayer O has", scoreo, "point(s)")
               p = p + 1
               pagain(scoreo, scorex)
               
           elif board[0] + board[4] + board[8] == "o o o ":
               scoreo = scoreo + 1
               print("\n\nO Wins\nPlayer O has", scoreo, "point(s)")
               p = p + 1
               pagain(scoreo, scorex)
               
           elif board[2] + board[4] + board[6] == "o o o ":
               scoreo = scoreo + 1
               print("\n\nO Wins\nPlayer O has", scoreo, "point(s)")
               p = p + 1
               pagain(scoreo, scorex)
               
           elif board[0] + board[3] + board[6] == "o o o ":
               scoreo = scoreo + 1
               print("\n\nO Wins\nPlayer O has", scoreo, "point(s)")
               p = p + 1
               pagain(scoreo, scorex)
               
           elif board[1] + board[4] + board[7] == "o o o ":
               scoreo = scoreo + 1
               print("\n\nO Wins\nPlayer O has", scoreo, "point(s)")
               p = p + 1
               pagain(scoreo, scorex)
               
           elif board[2] + board[5] + board[8] == "o o o ":
               scoreo = scoreo + 1
               print("\n\nO Wins\nPlayer O has", scoreo, "point(s)")
               p = p + 1
               pagain(scoreo, scorex)
               
           elif "# " not in board:
               print("\n\nTie.\nPlayer O has", oscore, "point(s).\nPlayer X has", xscore, "point(s)")
               p = p + 1
               pagain()
               
               
#For X
           x = input("\nWhere do you want to place your X letter?(a1, a2, a3...): ")
           if x == "a1":
               board[0] = "x "
               game()
           elif x == "a2":
               board[1] = "x "
               game()
           elif x == "a3":
               board[2] = "x "
               game()
           elif x == "b1":
               board[3] = "x "
               game()
           elif x == "b2":
               board[4] = "x "
               game()
           elif x == "b3":
               board[5] = "x "
               game()
           elif x == "c1":
               board[6] = "x "
               game()
           elif x == "c2":
               board[7] = "x "
               game()
           elif x == "c3":
               board[8] = "x "
               game()
           else:
               print("\nInvalid, you lost your turn.")
#X wins 
           if board[0] + board[1] + board[2] == "x x x ":
               scorex = scorex + 1
               print("\n\nO Wins\nPlayer X has", scoreo, "point(s)")
               p = p + 1
               pagain(scoreo, scorex)
               
           elif board[3] + board[4] + board[5] == "x x x ":
               scorex = scorex + 1
               print("\n\nO Wins\nPlayer X has", scoreo, "point(s)")
               p = p + 1
               pagain(scoreo, scorex)
               
           elif board[6] + board[7] + board[8] == "x x x ":
               scorex = scorex + 1
               print("\n\nO Wins\nPlayer X has", scoreo, "point(s)")
               p = p + 1
               pagain(scoreo, scorex)
               
           elif board[0] + board[4] + board[8] == "x x x ":
               scorex = scorex + 1
               print("\n\nO Wins\nPlayer X has", scoreo, "point(s)")
               p = p + 1
               pagain(scoreo, scorex)
           elif board[2] + board[4] + board[6] == "x x x ":
               scorex = scorex + 1
               print("\n\nO Wins\nPlayer X has", scoreo, "point(s)")
               p = p + 1
               pagain(scoreo, scorex)
               
               
           elif board[0] + board[3] + board[6] == "x x x ":
               scorex = scorex + 1
               print("\n\nO Wins\nPlayer X has", scoreo, "point(s)")
               p = p + 1
               pagain(scoreo, scorex)
               
           elif board[1] + board[4] + board[7] == "x x x ":
               scorex = scorex + 1
               print("\n\nO Wins\nPlayer X has", scoreo, "point(s)")
               p = p + 1
               pagain(scoreo, scorex)
               
           elif board[2] + board[5] + board[8] == "x x x ":
               scorex = scorex + 1
               print("\n\nO Wins\nPlayer X has", scoreo, "point(s)")
               p = p + 1
               pagain(scoreo, scorex)
               
           elif "# " not in board:
               print("\n\nTie.\nPlayer O has", oscore, "point(s).\nPlayer X has", xscore, "point(s)")
               p = p + 1
               pagain()

               
wholegame(scoreo, scorex) 

#create if statements to make acceptions(so you cant overite the others positions)
#Unexpected input(Ex: If someone doesn't type a1 then say invali
```

Comment: Only allow to change cells which have `#`?

Comment: It might be easier to save your board as a dict where the keys are `a1`, `c3`, etc. Since Python 3.7 dicts are insertion ordered so you even get a list-like behavior for printing...

Comment: One idea is to create another boolean array of the same size as board, and if a value is inserted to that particular cell of the board, set the boolean to true. In the next loop, process only if that cell is not initialized.

Comment: What is the problem with the current code?

Answer (score 0):

```
if o == "a1" and board[0] == "# ":
```

will check if the square is empty. However, since you individually test every condition, you will need to add the `and board[n] == "# "` to all of your conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
       if o == "a1" and board[0] != "o " :
           board[0] = "o "
           game()
           
       elif o == "a2" and board[1] != "o ":
           board[1] = "o "
           game()
       elif o == "a3" and board[2] != "o ":
           board[2] = "o "
           game()
       elif o == "b1" and board[3] != "o ":
       ...
```

And continue like this with the rest of the if statements